# How will kafka Connector publish a record to a topic if mode is timestamp and column has null value

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

This is more of a logical question than technical one.

I was just studying about the **mode config** of **jdbc source connector** and had a question in mind.

If Source Kafka connector has:

```
   "mode": "timestamp"
   "validate.non.null":"false"
```

Can it bring the data in topic?

If yes, how and after which record will it bring the row/record in topic.

PS: There is **no column in table** which can be used as an **incremental column.**

Comment: If it has no timestamp, why set that mode? The query would then filter all rows out

Comment: The table has a timestamp column just one (or more) record(s) have NULL value for it.....

Comment: Okay, and `SELECT * WHERE ts >= (some number)` does _what_ when you query your table?